# Prove a statement about a conditional Diophantine equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Prove the following statement.

If the variable, $a$, is a rational number, then the following conditional Diophantine equation is false over the positive integers (except for the rational variable, $a$) where $0 < a < m$ and $m > 2$:

$$s = r \cdot \left(\frac14\right)^{1/m} \cdot \frac{(r^a - 1)^{2/m}}{(r^a)^{1/m}}.$$

Here are the relevant **Fermat Equations**: $$t^m  =  s^m + r^m$$ where $$r^{m/2-a/2} =  t^{m/2}-s^{m/2}$$ and $$r^{m/2+a/2} =  t^{m/2}+s^{m/2}.$$

**Relevant Reference Links**:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/300080369_A_Simpler_Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem

'Searching for a Valid Proof of the ABC-conjecture,
https://www.math10.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=1793&start=40

'Proof of Fermat's Last Theorem by Prof. A. Wiles and Prof. R. Taylor' explained by Prof. N. Boston,
https://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/869.pdf

'A proof of ABC conjecture after Mochizuki' by Prof. Go Yamashita, 
http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~gokun/DOCUMENTS/abc_ver6.pdf

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The equation, $$s = r \cdot \left(\frac14\right)^{1/m} \cdot \frac{(r^a - 1)^{2/m}}{(r^a)^{1/m}},$$ implies the equation,$$ \frac{r}{s} \cdot  \frac{(r^a - 1)^{2/m}}{(r^a)^{1/m}}= 4^{1/m}.$$  But, the expression, $$4^{1/m},$$ is an irrational number when ***m > 2***.

Therefore, the expression, $$\frac{(r^a - 1)^{2/m}}{(r^a)^{1/m}},$$ is also an irrational number when ***m > 2***.

So either the expression, $$(r^a - 1)^{2/m}$$ or the expression, $$(r^a)^{1/m}$$ is an irrational number, or both expressions are irrational numbers.

Thus, the equation, $$\frac{s}{r} = \left(\frac14\right)^{1/m} \cdot \frac{(r^a - 1)^{2/m}}{(r^a)^{1/m}},$$  implies  $$\frac{k^{m}}{4^{m-1}} = \frac{(r^a - 1)^{2}}{r^a}$$ for some positive rational number, ***k***.

Or simply, we have the equation, $$\frac{s}{r}=\frac{k}{4}$$  which implies
$$s = \frac{k \cdot r}{4}.$$

But, $$r^{m} + s^{m} = t^{m}$$ which implies $$r^{m} +\frac{k^{m} \cdot r^{m}}{4^{m}} = (1+\frac{k^{m}}{4^{m}})*r^{m}=(\frac{4^{m}+k^{m}}{4^{m}})*r^{m} =t^{m}.$$

Equivalently, we have the following equation, $$t=\frac{(4^{m}+k^{m})^{1/m}}{4}*r.$$

We let $$l^{m} = 4^{m}+k^{m}$$ for some positive rational number, ***l***.

Or equivalently, we have **the important equation**, $$l^{m}-k^{m}=(l-k)\cdot\frac{l^{m}-k^{m}}{l-k} = 4^{m}.$$

Now, we construct **the two crucial equations**:  $$l-k = λ$$ and $$\frac{l^{m}-k^{m}}{l-k} = l^{m-1} + l^{m-2}\cdot k + ··· + l\cdot k^{m-2}+ k^{m-1}=\frac{4^{m}}{λ}$$ for some positive rational number, ***λ***, such that $$ 0 < λ <4^{m}.$$

If ***m=2***, then we compute the **positive rational solutions**: $$ k = \frac{16+λ^{2}}{2λ} -λ$$ and $$l = \frac{16+λ^{2}}{2λ}.$$

If ***m=3***, then we compute the **irrational solutions**: $$ k = \frac{\sqrt\frac{256-λ^{3}}{λ}}{2\cdot\sqrt{3}}-\frac{λ}{2}$$ and $$l = \frac{\sqrt\frac{256-λ^{3}}{λ}}{2\cdot\sqrt{3}}+\frac{λ}{2},$$ since the expression, $$\frac{256-λ^{3}}{3λ} =\frac{1}{3}\cdot(\frac{256}{λ}-λ^{2})=\frac{1}{3}\cdot(\frac{16}{\sqrt{λ}}+λ)\cdot(\frac{16}{\sqrt{λ}}-λ) = ...$$ is clearly **not a perfect square** via method of infinite descent.

If ***m=4***, then we compute the **irrational solutions**, ***k*** and ***l = k + λ,*** where, $$k= \frac{1}{2}\cdot(\frac{(2304λ^{2}+\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{λ^{12} +1769472λ^{4}})^{1/3} }{3^{2/3}λ}-\frac{λ^{3}}{3^{1/3}\cdot(2304λ^{2}+\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{λ^{12} +1769472λ^{4}})^{1/3}})-\frac{λ}{2}.$$

If ***m=5***, then we compute the **irrational solutions**, **k** and ***l = k + λ,*** where, $$k=\frac{\sqrt{5}\cdot\sqrt{2\cdot\sqrt{5}\cdotλ\cdot\sqrt{λ(λ^{5}+4096})-5λ^{4}}-5λ^{2}}{10λ}.$$

As for ***m>5***, solutions in ***k*** and in ***l*** may require knowledge and application of **Galois theory**.  Thus, solutions in radicals may or may not exist according to that theory.  Hmm.  That will be cheating since the great Fermat, we assumed, did not have such a powerful and elegant tool in his toolkit.  Hmm...

How to proceed (without Galois theory) with **the key equation**, $$(k+λ)^{m-1} + (k+λ)^{m-2}\cdot k + ··· + (k+λ)\cdot k^{m-2}+ k^{m-1}=\frac{4^{m}}{λ},$$ when ***m>5***?

Have we answered our question?  There are **no positive rational solutions** in ***k*** for the above equation when ***m > 2***.  And that statement is a contradiction since we assumed ***k*** is a positive rational number. Thus, we conclude that ***our statement about the conditional Diophantine equation is true!***

***Remarks:***
The great Fermat was right about **FLT (Fermat's Last Theorem)** without knowing about the **Fundamental Theorem of Algebra** and without knowing the profound insight which the great Galois had discovered in 1830 almost two centuries after Fermat's discovery of **FLT**...

So, Fermat, Euler, Gauss, Eisenstein, Dirichlet, Germain, Abel, Ruffini, ..., Kummer, Dedekind,  Lagrange, and Galois solved FLT!  Wow!

---

**Reference links**:

[Why are there no positive rational solutions for the following Diophantine equation over the field of rational numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034656/why-are-there-no-positive-rational-solutions-for-the-following-diophantine-equat)

'Rational Root Theorem',  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem;

'Eisenstein's Criterion',  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion;

'Abel-Ruffini Theorem', https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem;

'Galois Theory for Beginners', http://www.math.jhu.edu/~smahanta/Teaching/Spring10/Stillwell.pdf;

'Galois Theory', http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/MA3D5/Galois.pdf;

'Fields and Galois Theory',  http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf;

'Newton's Method for solving our key equation *numerically* when ***m>5'***,   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method.

---

Comment: Q.E.D.  The great French mathematician and jurist, Pierre de Fermat, was right about FLT!   Thank Lord GOD! Amen! :-)

Comment: Not so fast about FLT.  There's absolutely no reason to believe that $a$ is rational, and in the generic case it will be transcendental.  So the result would be of very limited utility for FLT.

Comment: Maybe not so fast for this proof.  It is entirely possible for an irrational number raised to the power of $1/a$ to be rational.  Take $\sqrt{2}^(1/a)$ where $a=1/4$.  In any case this section warrants greater justification.

Comment: Without making judgments on this specific proof, I can see that the structure of the proof is similar to that of other false proofs: rewriting the same equation in ways that are not essentially different ways until either an algebra mistake is made or an unwarranted assumption about some number being rational is pulled out of thin air.  This happens 99% of the time, so i suggest you make sure your claims are justified if you wish to have any confidence in your proof.

Comment: @Erick Wong  We'll agree to disagree.  Your input is not helpful here ...

Comment: 1) You make the unjustified claim that $\sqrt{64-\lambda^2}/\sqrt{3\lambda}$ is irrational with no trace of a proof.  2) You immediately jump from the unproven case $m=3$ to "$m>2$".  3) The comment about "not sufficiently dense" is meaningless and nonsensical.  It would seem you have vastly underestimated the burden of proof required of your claim.

Comment: Hmm.  I am convinced the proof is correct!  Q.E.D.

Comment: The proof is not convincing to any other reader.  What is obvious about $64/\lambda - \lambda^2$ not being a perfect square?  You also missed the point that it is not this quantity that need be a square, but 1/3 of this.  Since $m=3$ is not obvious, there are countless other non-obvious claims hidden in $m>3$ that you have not covered.  You may have good reason to believe it can be repaired, but what you have presented falls far short of a proof.

Comment: Hmm.  Someone is deleting my comments here.  I have flagged other comments to no avail.  Life is not fair... Please stop deleting my comments.  Thank you.

Comment: FLT is sound, and the great Fermat was right!   :-)