# Why are there no positive rational solutions for the following Diophantine equation over the field of rational numbers?

Tags: galois-theory, diophantine-equations, rational-numbers

Please consider the following Diophantine equation for any integer, ***m > 5***:

$$(k + λ)^{m-1}  +  (k + λ)^{m-2} \cdot k  +  . . .  +  (k + λ) \cdot k^{m-2}  +  k^{m-1} =   4^{m} /  λ$$

where the rational number,  ***λ***,  is such that $$0 <  λ <  4^{m}.$$

Applying **Galois theory**, can anyone explain why there are **no positive rational solutions** in ***k*** for the **following irreducible (over the set of rational numbers) polynomial equations of degree, m ≥ 6,** whose **real solutions**, **k**,  are probably **irrational numbers or transcendental numbers**?

**Please do not apply Fermat's Last Theorem (FLT).**

If ***m = 6***, we have the following equation:  $$6λ\cdot k^{5}+15λ^{2}\cdot k^{4} + 20λ^{3}\cdot k^{3} + 15λ^{4}\cdot k^{2} + 6λ^{5}\cdot k + λ^{6} = 4096$$  with $$0 <  λ <  4096.$$

If ***m = 7***, we have the following equation:  $$7λ\cdot k^{6}+21λ^{2}\cdot k^{5} + 35λ^{3}\cdot k^{4} + 35λ^{4}\cdot k^{3} + 21λ^{5}\cdot k^{2} + 7λ^{6}\cdot k + λ^{7} = 16384$$  with $$0 <  λ <  16384.$$

**Reference**: Wolfram Cloud (https://www.wolframcloud.com/) code to generate the above  equations for values, ***m=6*** and ***m=7***:

f[m_]:= (n=m;l = k+[Lambda] ; Return[{Together[[Lambda]*(l^n-k^n)/(l-k)],4^n}]).

**Reference link**: [Prove a statement about a conditional Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993460/prove-a-statement-about-a-conditional-diophantine-equation/1997276#1997276).

Comment: Hint: multiply both sides by $(k+\lambda)-k=\lambda$.

Comment: @dxiv  That's correct!   λ = λ.   But, I hoping someone who is am expert in Galois theory and in field theory could help me.  I am confident the above equation is not solvable over the rational numbers.    And it may take me a few weeks to prove this with Galois theory.

Answer (score 1):

[ *EDIT* ]  The answer below was posted before the question was edited to specifically ask *for* Galois proofs *not* using FLT. From the references that were added, the question appears to be related to an attempt at an independent proof of FLT.  While the answer no longer applies to the question as restated, I am leaving it here just so that others are not tempted to repost the same obvious answer.

---

Multiplying both sides by $(k+\lambda)-k=\lambda$ gives:

$$(k+\lambda)^m - k^m = 4^m \quad \iff \quad k^m + 4^m = (k+\lambda)^m$$

By FLT the latter has no non-trivial rational solutions for $\;m \gt 2\;$ and the condition $k \gt 0$ excludes the trivial solutions $\;k=0, \lambda=4\;$ and (for *odd* $m$) $\;k=-4,\lambda=4\;$.

As a side note, the premise $0 \lt \lambda \lt 4^m$ is not necessary for the conclusion to hold, and $m \gt 2$ is sufficient (rather than $m \gt 5$).

Comment: Your answer is not the right answer.

Comment: @Dave It does answer the question as asked. Please point at what exact problem you see with this answer.

Comment: Again, I hoping someone who is am expert in Galois theory and in field theory could help me. I am confident the above equation is not solvable over the rational numbers. And it may take me a few weeks to prove this with Galois theory.

Comment: @Dave My answer proves it in a couple of lines using FLT, and I still don't know what you find "wrong" with it. If you have some particular, different type of answer in mind, then you should spell that out in the question so that others don't waste time posting answers which you are not interested in.

Comment: It's not the answer I'm seeking.  Can you explain a solution using Galois theory?